# In Rio de Janeiro, which lane should I be using when biking and there's a bus-only lane?

Tags: bicycles, brazil, rio-de-janeiro

In some places in Rio the rightmost lane is bus-only (and I believe taxis can drive there too). It's clearly marked with ÔNIBUS written all over and blue line between it and other lanes.

I was cycling on the next rightmost lane, and I was constantly being honked at by drivers. Then I moved to that bue lane and taxis passing there were honking at me. There was no bike-only lane (maybe they were doing that just to signal that they're about to pass me though).

Can I be be using that lane then? I didn't find any clear info on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

In Rio, there are a bunch of dedicated cycle lanes roughly following the coast, from the old port all the way to Barra. They're easy to recognise, with regularly stamped images of bikes on the road and almost always using red pigment mixed in with the tarmac.

If you're on a road that doesn't have a dedicated cycle lane... you have to use your best judgment.

When cycling in Rio, I stay on the right of the road, sometimes moving onto the sidewalk, depending on how crowded either the road or the sidewalk is.